# SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length android

Tags: android

i have create an app for add frame over image(Frame is in png file) it is working on my cell  phone  it gives error on xperia mobile phone , how can i detect the problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an error (i.e. it's causing a problem with your application)?

I've seen this in logs of many devices, including mine (Nexus 4). It's generally related to using a custom keyboard application. In particular SwiftKey seems to cause it a lot (see for example this [bug report](http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/2994580-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-)).

Unless you believe these messages are related to crashes or any other unwanted behavior, I wouldn't worry about them.